hashes that support a stream structure
This is mostly academic curiosity because I'm interested in communication systems,  power requirements, padding costs and time.  Generally, hashes occur on blocks, and for this example, I'm just going to say we have 64-bit blocks made up of 8, 8-bit words.  It's sometimes very costly for me to wait around for data to arrive in the world of comms.  An interesting thing that does happen is that when I am waiting around, I have more electrical power available than I do when the data being streamed in, so I have processing time as I'm waiting for data to arrive.  You would have to initially pad the register or zeros, but you could then just shift in a byte, run some logic, shift in a byte, run some logic... repeat.
Is there a hash that "shifts in" small amounts of data at a time?  It can be as wide as necessary in total bits.  This would make it useful for communication streams with a significant savings in power, especially when you have gaps between arrivals of data.  It also lets you stop at any point as you are on byte boundaries instead of block boundaries.

I believe this can be addressed by using a FIFO along with a standard hash (SHA-2, SHA-3); when you're in receiving mode, you take the data and insert it into the FIFO.  When you're in between-communication-burst mode, you take the data from the FIFO, and add it to the hash.  Not a very exciting answer - however, when it comes to security, "not exciting" can be a good thing...

Tricky, there is a reason why hashes are commonly build upon symmetric cipher-like structures that have a wide block size. But hey, what do I know, maybe you can have the rounds shift with the input, with a penalty at the start & end.

@poncho Yeah, just waiting until the block is full is a common method, but I think that bdegnan is looking for a more direct solution. But I agree, as long as you don't mind waiting for the first block you can perform the rounds of the previous block while waiting or receiving input data of the next one.

suspend and resume?

Sponge constructions such as SHA3 have a parameter $r$ called the rate which determines how much input data is absorbed in each step (and subsequently how much (extensible) output is produced at each step).
In theory $r$ could be chosen as small as 1-bit, though efficiency usually dictates larger rates.
A quick google on low-rate sponge hash functions turns up the SPONGENT design, which has (low security) version with $r=8$ and large constructions with $r=16$. It has reputable authors, but I do not know how much cryptanalysis has been performed.

What about the performance?

@kelalaka Data on the hardware performance of SPONGENT in comparison to other hash function can be seen in Table 2 of the paper on page 12.

This is somewhat like using only x bytes with x <= n for block ops of hash functions. Usually the rate $r$ varies depending on the size of the state, which is itself a security parameter. In other words, this will indeed lower the amount of bytes until the sponge function can be executed, but it will increase the state / security and it will of course require more instructions per byte as well.
